# Time Complexity of Shift and Add Multiplication

Tags: time-complexity, multiplication

I am trying to figure out the time complexity of the computer's shift and add multiplication algorithm based on the image below:

[image]

So, if an integer is A bits wide and each step of the operation takes B time units, and an           addition step is always done, would the time complexity of this algorithm be O(n*n) which each shift and add being O(n)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are counting bit operations, you get O(n*(n+m)), when n is number of bits in the smallest operand and m is the number of bits in product.  (compare both operands, and choose the smallest as the multiplier; loop exit condition is shifted multiplier is zero).  Since m = n + k where k is the number of bits in the multiplicand, you get in essence O(n^2).

But that is unrealistic in practice.

On most CPUs, shift (esp. by 1 unit) instructions and add instructions take unit time.  So if you want complexity in terms of unit machine instructions, shift-and-add multiply is O(n).

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes so much more sense now!